# URL routing not working

Tags: silverstripe

I'm trying to get URL routing working so that I can call functions of a controller through AJAX. The AJAX calls are formed as "ajax/{name of function in controller}/{ID to pass to function}".

I've added the following to my routes.yml:

```
Director:
  rules:
    'ajax': 'TakeActionPage_Controller'
```

In my TakeActionPage_Controller, I have:

```
private static $url_handlers = array(
    'electoratesfrompostcode/$ID' => 'electoratesfrompostcode',
);

public function electoratesfrompostcode(SS_HTTPRequest $request)
{
    $id = (int)$request->param('ID');

    return $this->getElectoratesFromPostcode($id);
}
```

This is not working. When I add `?debug_request=1` to the URL of the TakeActionPage, I get:

```
Debug (line 250 of RequestHandler.php): Testing 'electoratesfrompostcode/$ID' with '' on TakeActionPage_Controller
Debug (line 250 of RequestHandler.php): Testing '$Action//$ID/$OtherID' with '' on TakeActionPage_Controller
Debug (line 258 of RequestHandler.php): Rule '$Action//$ID/$OtherID' matched to action 'handleAction' on TakeActionPage_Controller. Latest request params: array ( 'Action' => NULL, 'ID' => NULL, 'OtherID' => NULL, )
Debug (line 184 of RequestHandler.php): Action not set; using default action method name 'index'
```

I'm not really sure what to make of those debug messages. Any ideas for how to get this working?

Comment: What's the actual URL that debug_request is for? Also did you paste all your code above of left something out, since it says you have this rule in your page controller `'$Action//$ID/$OtherID'` but it's not in your code?

Answer (score 1):

Try adding an `$allowed_actions` array

`public static $allowed_actions = array('electoratesfrompostcode');`

See the docs:
http://doc.silverstripe.org/framework/en/topics/controller#usage

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that the code I posted in the question is actually working. I previously had different code which was not working, and which returned the same debug info when using `?debug_request=1`. I then changed the code to what is posted in the question and was still getting the same debug info so I assumed it was still not working, but it actually was.

Not really sure what to make of the debug info if it shows the exact same message for working code and non-working code.